# wlan0 No such device found

Tags: linux, wifi, connection-sharing

[image]I m new to linux.
I changed my wifi password and was trying to reconnect to it but I failed when I type

`ifconfig wlan0`

I get error message. something like no such device found

Comment: Welcome to U&L please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/330777/edit) by adding the output of `iwconfig` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` and specify your linux distro

Comment: i edited it with the output of iwconfig and lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

Comment: i m currently using my net through USB

Comment: the answer of @Zumo de Vidrio is correct

Comment: how do i connect to my new wifi please provide me steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you actually have a network device called wlan0? It seems that your wifi NIC is called "wlp5s0".

Comment: So how do i connect to any wifi ?

Answer (score 0):

Under systemd your interface is renamed from `wlan0` to `wlp5s0`

After changing the wifi password , clic on *Edit connections* > select your Wifi > *Edit* > *Wifi Security* then change the password. Save and connect from the nm-applet

Also you can edit your connection from the terminal by runing : `sudo nmtui`

Edit a connection >> select the wifi connecion >> edit >> change the password >> OK

[Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)

Comment: What's `systemd` and why does it rename the interface?